# Canvas not appearing and its saying tkinter is not defined (tkinter python)

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I'm new to programming and the book I'm using gives the below code. The canvas is not appearing when i run the program and the console is giving me an error message  'unable to detect unidentified names' and '(insert variable) may be unidentified or identified by star imports' --  my book is saying its part of the standard library can anyone help explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from tkinter import *
def hello():
    print("hello buddy")
tk = Tk()
btn = Button(tk, text="click me!", command=hello)
btn.pack()
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(tk, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()
```

Answer (score 2):

since you imported tkinter with the * sign, you do not need to add `tkinter` before a tkinter method/class call. Everything in tkinter is loaded to the program. So simply remove the `tkinter.` from the canvas line and it should work.

Comment: thank you but it didn't work